# Скрипт на Python для Cisco-устройств и проблема с циклом

Tags: python, cisco

Скрипт

```
import sys
import time
import paramiko 
import os
import cmd
import datetime



#set date and time
now = datetime.datetime.now()

#authentication
HOST = open('d:\python\hosts.txt')
USER = 'user'
PASSWORD = 'password'
secret = 'password'

all_ips = [ip.rstrip() for ip in HOST]


#prefix files for backup
filename_prefix ='cisco_backup'+ip

print all_ips
#ssh session starts
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(ip, username=USER, password=PASSWORD)

#ssh shell
chan = client.invoke_shell()
time.sleep(1)
#enter enable secret
chan.send('en\n')
chan.send(secret +'\n')
time.sleep(1)
#terminal lenght for no paging 
chan.send('term len 0\n')
time.sleep(1)
#show config and write output
chan.send('sh run\n')
time.sleep(10)
output = chan.recv(99999)
#show output config and write file with prefix, date and time
print output
filename = "%s_%.2i-%.2i-%i_%.2i-%.2i-%.2i" % (filename_prefix,now.day,now.month,now.year,now.hour,now.minute,now.second)
f = open(filename, 'a')
f.write(output)
f.close()
#close ssh session
client.close()
```

В файл hosts пишу несколько ip-адресов, но на выходе получаю только один файл  с последним адресом. Остальных нет.

Где я не прав? По логике, вроде бы я открываю файл, читаю адреса из него и прогоняю дальше все в цикле.

Comment: А где цикл? Единственный, который я вижу формирует all_ips, которые никуда кроме как на печать не выводятся...

Comment: то есть, все остальное в этот цикл не попадает?

Comment: Нет, в чем вы легко можете убедиться поставив в начале "остального" print "start"

Comment: Не сильно понимаю как это в цикл запихать. Пробую еще вот так
f = open('hosts.txt')
for ip in f.readlines(): 

Но тоже самое выходит...

Comment: А что именно вы хотите сделать? Я бы рекомендовал вам начать с минимального кода, который на каждой итерации цикла что-то печатает.

Comment: Я пытаюсь брать из файла построчно адреса и по каждому адресу прогонять такую процедуру, начиная с "#ssh session starts"

Comment: Начните с печати каждой из строк файла, потом постепенно добавляйте в тело цикла остальной код.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов вот только тела цикла-то нет :)

Answer (score 2):

Могу предположить, вы ошибочно трактуете код `[ip.rstrip() for ip in HOST]`. Он не инициирует цикл. Это так называемый [генератор списка](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Всё, что он делает, так это записывает в переменную `all_ips` новый список, сформированный путём применения `str.rstrip()` к каждой строке из файла HOSTS.

Генераторные выражения, без сомнения, крайне мощное средство языка. Но в данном случае, будет логично использовать обычный [цикл](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements):

```
for ip in hosts:
    filename_prefix = 'cisco_backup' + ip
    # И прочие ваши действия с элементом списка
```

Буду не вежлив и не оригинален, но читайте [доки](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html), пожалуйста.

Comment: кстати, в Питоне 3, локальные имена в list comprehension такие как `ip` не могут убежать из контекста. OP получил бы `NameError`.